# saving the model in a loop yii

Tags: arrays, yii, models, saving-data

I need to save the field value several times by separating them by commas. I am getting the values,but i need to store each value in model in a loop.

```
$subModel->name = $_POST['Model']['keywords'];
$keyword = explode(",", $subModel->name);    
for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($keyword)-1; $i++)
{
    //echo $keyword[$i]."<br/>";
    $subModel->name = $keyword[$i];
    $subModel->save();
}
```

It is storing only last value, can anyone tell me how to store into my model several times for every value one time in submodel in a loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set `$subModel->isNewRecord = true` in each iteration and also unset (or manually set to the value of your choice) the model's id field. It would look something like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=sizeof($keyword)-1; $i++)
{
    // if $subModel->name is not the primary key for that model, unset the PK here:
    // $subModel->id = null
    $subModel->name = $keyword[$i];
    $subModel->isNewRecord = true;
    $subModel->save();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..id is the primary key here. and i'm getting this erro....CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `subModel` (`name`, `id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1)

Comment: @Developer: That's because you have not set `id` to `null`. Did you read the commented-out lines?

Comment: i also need to store the names unique values..can you pls tell me how can i check this and save

Comment: @Developer: Sorry, but I cannot write your code for you. There are many online resources that explain how validation works in Yii.

Comment: @mehdinejati: Otherwise the loop would try to insert with an existing PK and it would fail because of the duplicate.

Comment: I am facing a problem having name blank for above example. Only first name is saved while rest are all blank. Is there a problem?

Comment: I am forced to create new model instance to save every row one by one because of the weird behavior of saving blank names.